# AJAX me devuelve el registro ya insertado de la bd no el que acabo de ingresar

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, mvc

```
  public function ctrAgregarUsuarios(){

    if (isset($_POST['usuario'])) {

      if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nombres"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['usuario']) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['password']) ) {
        
            $password_segura=password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $tabla = "usuarios";
            $datos=array(
              'nombres' => $_POST['nombres'],
              'usuario'=>$_POST['usuario'],
              'password' =>$password_segura,
              'perfil'=>$_POST['perfil']);

            $consulta = new UsuarioModelo();
            $salida=$consulta->mdlAgregarUsuarios($tabla,$datos);
            echo json_encode($salida);

            


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es lo que quieres que te devuelva en sí? ¿Qué hace el método `mdlAgregarUsuarios()`? ¿Qué depuraciones has hecho?

Comment: A.Cedano falto los otro codigos pero no me dejaba publicarlo el problema yo hago una peticion AJAX para insertar datos me inserta en la bd pero la respuesta ajax me muestra el usuario ya registrado no el que acabo de ingresar

Comment: No se logra entender lo que quieres. Generalmente cuando insertas un registro no necesitas esos datos de vuelta porque ya los tenías (de hecho los envías para que sean insertados). Lo único que no tendrías sería el ID que se generaría al ocurrir la inserción. ¿Es ese el dato que te interesa? La pregunta no es clara, sólo intento adivinar lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Sucede porque en $tabla le estas diciendo que te muestre un usuario cualquier, deberias tener un query que te limite a un solo registro:

Eje:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuarios ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: $tabla sólo es el nombre de la tabla a actualizar. **No es una consulta** El problema radica en que no hay control directo sobre lo que devuelve el método mdlAgregarUsuarios() y evidentemente no se consulta el último registro insertado. Por otra parte ¿cómo sabes que la tabla usa un campo identificador autonumérico de nombre 'id'? **no hay algo en el código que lo indique**